# connect base class signal to inherited class slot

Tags: base-class, inherited

I have a question - how to connect base class signal to inherited class slot.
I`ve got a code like this

```
class A: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    A(){}
    void EmitSignal()
    {
    emit(Asignal());
    }
signals:
    void Asignal(); 
};

class B: public A
{
public:
    B();
public slots:
    void Bslot()
        {
        //dosmth
        }
};

B::B()
{
    connect(this, SIGNAL(Asignal()), this, SLOT(Bslot()));
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    B Bobject;
    B.EmitSignal();
}
```

and when I call `B.EmitSignal()` I suppose to have `Bslot()` called, but I got a message in output window

> QObject::connect: No such slot A::Bslot().

How can I achieve `Bslot()` execution?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. I forgot Q_OBJECT macro in inherited class